# How do we send a canvas image data as an attachment to a server on Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, gnu-smalltalk, pharo-5, pharo-6

How do we send or upload a data file to a server on Pharo. I saw some example of sending file from a directory on the machine.
It works fine.

```html
ZnClient new
  url: MyUrl;
  uploadEntityfrom: FileLocator home /Path to the file;
  put
```

In my case I don't want to send/upload file downloaded on a machine but instead I want to send/upload a file hosted somewhere or data I retrieved over the network and send it attached to another server.
How can we do that ?

Comment: How do you want to send the file over the network?  smb share, webdav, ftp(s), NFS or some other way?   Could you be more specific?

Comment: Either using ftp or webdav. @tukan

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer when it fits your needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your previous questions I presume you are using linux.  The issue here is not within Smalltak/Pharo, but the network mapping.

### FTP

If you want to have a **ftp**, don't forget it is sending password in plaintext, set-up it a way you can mount it.  There are probably plenty of ways to do this but you can try using `curlftpfs`.  You need kernel module `fuse` for that, make sure you have it loaded.  If it is not loaded you can do so via `modprobe fuse`.

The usage would be:

```
curlftpfs ftp.yoursite.net /mnt/ftp/ -o user=username:password,allow_other
```

where you fill *username*/*password*.  The option `allow_other` allows other users at the system to use your mount.
(for more details you can see arch wiki and its [curlftpfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CurlFtpFS))

### Webdav

For **webdav** I would use the same approach, this time using `davfs`

You would manually mount it via `mount` command:

```
mount -t davfs https://yoursite.net:<port>/path /mnt/webdav
```

There are two reasonable way to setup it - `systemd` or `fstab`.  The information below is taken from [davfs2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Davfs2) Arch wiki:

For `systemd`:

`/etc/systemd/system/mnt-webdav-service.mount`

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount WebDAV Service
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Mount]
What=http(s)://address:<port>/path
Where=/mnt/webdav/service
Options=uid=1000,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=2775,grpid
Type=davfs
TimeoutSec=15

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You can create an *systemd automount* unit to set a **timeout**:

`/etc/systemd/system/mnt-webdav-service.automount`

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount WebDAV Service
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Automount]
Where=/mnt/webdav
TimeoutIdleSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

For the `fstab` way it is easy if you have edited `fstab` before (it behaves same as any other `fstab` entry):

`/etc/fstab`

```
https://webdav.example/path /mnt/webdav davfs rw,user,uid=username,noauto 0 0
```

For webdav you can even store the credentials securely:

Create a secrets file to store credentials for a WebDAV-service using `~/.davfs2/secrets` for user, and `/etc/davfs2/secrets` for root:

```
/etc/davfs2/secrets

https://webdav.example/path davusername davpassword
```

Make sure the secrets file contains the correct permissions, for root mounting:

```
# chmod 600 /etc/davfs2/secrets
# chown root:root /etc/davfs2/secrets
```

And for user mounting:

```
$ chmod 600 ~/.davfs2/secrets
```

### Back to your Pharo/Smalltalk code:

I presume you read the above and have either **/mnt/ftp** or **/mnt/webdav** mounted.

For e.g. **ftp** your code would simply take from the mounted directory:

```
ZnClient new
  url: MyUrl;
  uploadEntityfrom: FileLocator '/mnt/ftp/your_file_to_upload';
  put
```

### **Edit** Bassed on the comments.

The issue is that the configuration of the `ZnClient` is in the Pharo itself and the json file is also generated there.

One quick and dirty solution - would be to use above mentined with a shell command:

With **ftp** for example:

```
| commandOutput |

commandOutput := (PipeableOSProcess command: 'curlftpfs ftp.yoursite.net /mnt/ftp/ -o user=username:password,allow_other') output.
Transcript show: commandOutput.
```

Other approach is more sensible.  Is to use Pharo `FTP` or `WebDav` support via [FileSystemNetwork](http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/%7EUdoSchneider/FileSystemNetwork).

To load **ftp** only:

```
Gofer it
    smalltalkhubUser: 'UdoSchneider' project: 'FileSystemNetwork';
    configuration;
    load.
#ConfigurationOfFileSystemNetwork asClass project stableVersion load: 'FTP'
```

to load **Webdav** only:

```
Gofer it
    smalltalkhubUser: 'UdoSchneider' project: 'FileSystemNetwork';
    configuration;
    load.
#ConfigurationOfFileSystemNetwork asClass project stableVersion load: 'Webdav'
```

To get everything including tests:

```
Gofer it
    smalltalkhubUser: 'UdoSchneider' project: 'FileSystemNetwork';
    configuration;
    loadStable.
```

With that you should be able to get a file for example for `ftp`:

```
| ftpConnection wDir file |

"Open a connection"
ftpConnection := FileSystem ftp: 'ftp://ftp.sh.cvut.cz/'.
"Getting working directory"
wDir := ftpConnection workingDirectory.
file := '/Arch/lastsync' asFileReference.
"Close connection - do always!"
ftpConnection close.
```

Then your upload via (**ftp**) would look like this:

```
| ftpConnection wDir file |

"Open connection"
ftpConnection := FileSystem ftp: 'ftp://your_ftp'.
"Getting working directory"
wDir := ftpConnection workingDirectory.
file := '/<your_file_path' asFileReference.
ZnClient new
     url: MyUrl;
     uploadEntityfrom: FileLocator file;
     put
"Close connection - do always!"
ftpConnection close.
```

The **Webdav** would be similar.

Comment: In my case I retrieve a json file that is saved into a variable. Using the fileLocator I can't seem to assign a directory this way

Comment: @ludo Ah, that is completely different workflow than I imagined.  Could you please be more specific at your question.  How do you get your `json` file and how to you intend to use it.

Comment: Yes sure. I have a canvas where I can draw a rectangle. Then with Pharo I am able to collect the cords of this rectangle which I convert to a json. Now I need to send or upload this json as attachment to a server using a PUT request. So here I have a variable containing the Json.

Comment: @ludo Ok, where do you have do you then store the connection information to your FTP or WebDav?

Comment: I would normally use a simple ZnClient however I don't see much how to attach the json data.

Comment: @ludo Ah, I see.  I thought you have this information stored externally (outside Pharo).  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: No only internally. Thanks